# why this code can run ? double a[3]; a[1,1]=1;

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main()
{
    double a[3];  
    a[1,1]=1;
}
```

It passes the vs2013 compiler, and it is not 2D array.

Comment: The syntax for a 2D array would be a[1][1]

Answer (score 8):

You are invoking the [*comma operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). This evaluates its first operand, discards it, and returns the second one. So your code is the equivalent of

```
a[1] = 1;
```

The syntax for accessing an element of a 2D array would be

```
b[1][2] = 42;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a[1,1]=1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a[1]=1;
```

The expression `1,1` evaluates to `1`, because the first `1` is discarded and only the second `1` is evaluated. Read up on the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) for more info.

Comment: If I have a matrix class, and overload the operator [], then it is dangerous to use Matrix[i,j]

Comment: @liangbright: To explain why: overloading an `operator` can not change the number of parameters it takes, with one exception : `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression inside square brackets there is so-called comma operator.

```
a[1,1]=1;
```

Its value is the value of the last subexpression.

So this statement is equivalent to

```
a[1]=1;
```

This syntax as

```
a[1,1]=1;
```

is also valid in C# but it  sets an element of a two-dimensional array.

In C/C++ each index of a multidimensional array shall be enclosed in separate square brackets.

Here is a more interesting example with the comma operator

```
int main()
{
    double a[3];  
    size_t i = 0;  
    a[i++, i++]=1;
}
```

It is also equivalent to

```
    a[1]=1;
```